# jQuery function on array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the following code

```
var elements = $(".myClasses");
elements[1].animate({something},  1000);
```

If I use `$(".myClasses").animate(...)` it works, but why doesn't it work if I select just one element from the array?

I guess I maybe don't uderstand well the rules about objects or arrays.

Comment: Adding a `[0]` to a jQuery Object Array will return a DOM element instead of a jQuery element. Because `.animate()` is a jQuery method, it can only be used on jQuery objects. You're likely looking for `$(".myClasses").eq(1)` which is the jQuery equivalent to `[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `$(".myClasses")` returns a jQuery object, and when you access it as an array it simply returns the DOM node and not a jQuery object. If you want to access them by index, simply use:

- `$(elements[1])`, which converts the DOM node back into a jQuery object, so that you can apply jQuery methods to it, or
- `$(".myClasses").eq(1)`, which reduces a set of elements matched by the jQuery selector to a single element at the specified zero-based index. [See documentation for `.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: This arrives at the right advice but for the wrong reasons. It's perfectly fine to use `[]` to fetch elements from a jQuery object, but they are returned as raw DOM nodes. There's nothing wrong with `$('.myClasses')[1]`.

Comment: @meagar Thanks, I have updated my answer to reflect that. OP can of course convert `elements[1]` to a jquery object using `$(elements[1])` and that will work :) not my typical modus operandi tho.

Comment: Guys thank you a lot. I tried a lot, but I could never come alone to that conclusion. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use a jquery function you have to cast a jquery object you do it like

`$(elements[1]).animate(...`

Comment: This is a complete misuse of the term "cast". There's no casting involved here.